# How do I integrate$ \int\frac{1}{e^{2x}+e^x} \,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

How do I integrate following function?

$$
\int\frac{1}{e^{2x}+e^x} \,dx
$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. Please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $$\dfrac1{e^x(e^x+1)}=\dfrac{(e^x+1)-e^x}{e^x(e^x+1)}=e^{-x}-\dfrac1{e^x+1}$$

and use [How do I solve $\displaystyle\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{e^x + 1} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770114/how-do-i-solve-displaystyle-int-frac-mathrmdxex-1)

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

Set $e^x=u, x=\ln u\implies dx=\dfrac{du}u$

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{e^x(e^x+1)}=\int\dfrac{du}{u^2(u+1)}$$

Now use Partial fraction decomposition, $$\dfrac1{u^2(u+1)}=\dfrac Au+\dfrac B{u^2}+\dfrac C{u+1}$$

Answer (score 3):

And yet, one more approach is

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{e^{2x}+e^x}\,dx&=\int \frac{e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-x}}\,dx\\\\
&=\int \left(1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right)e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&=-e^{-x}+\int \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\,d\left(e^{-x}\right)\\\\
&=\log(1+e^{-x})-e^{-x}+C
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $e^x= t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle e^x dx = dt\Rightarrow dx = \frac{1}{e^x}dt = \frac{dt}{t}$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{e^x(e^x+1)}dx = \int\frac{1}{t^2(t+1)}dt$$
Now Let $\displaystyle t = \frac{1}{u}\;,$ Then $\displaystyle dt = -\frac{1}{u^2}du$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = -\int \frac{u}{u+1}du = -\int\frac{(u+1)-1}{u+1}du = -u+\ln|u+1|+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = -\frac{1}{t}+\ln\left|\frac{t+1}{t}\right|+\mathcal{C} =-\frac{1}{e^x}+\ln\left|\frac{e^x+1}{e^x}\right|+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = -e^{-x}+\ln|e^x+1|-x+\mathcal{C}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int\frac{1}{e^{2x}+e^x} \,dx = \int\frac{e^x\,dx}{e^{3x} + e^{2x}} = \int \frac{e^x\,dx}{(e^x)^2(e^x + 1)} = \int\frac{du}{u^2(u+1)}
$$
Then use partial fractions.