# What method can I use to solve$\int \frac {dx} {e^x - 1}$

Tags: integration

I have been staring at this question for about half an hour now.

*EDIT*

If you were wondering, this is not a dupe of the question "How to solve $\int \frac {dx} {e^x + 1}$ "

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F(e%5Ex-1)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770114/how-do-i-solve-displaystyle-int-frac-mathrmdxex-1

Comment: I don't really trust that thing to give a good answer. and anyway, I just wanted a few pointers on how to solve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**: Let $u = e^x - 1 \Rightarrow x = \ln(u+1)\Rightarrow dx = \dfrac{du}{u+1}$. Can you take it from here ?

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: you are very welcome buddy.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{dx}{e^{x}-1}=\int \frac{e^{-x}\,dx}{1-e^{-x}}$$

Substitute $t=e^{-x}$ integral reduces to ,

$$\int \frac{-dt}{1-t}$$