# integrating $\int \frac{1}{e^x +1}\:dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I've found a method for integration of  $\frac{1}{e^x +1}dx$. However none of the information I found explains the intuition. It might be clear for most people, but I was hoping that somebody could expand on it.

The problem of trying to u-substitute  $\frac{1}{e^x +1}dx$ becomes evident.

Since  $\frac{1}{e^x +1}dx$, where I substitute $e^x$ for u, gives me:

$$\int\frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{e^x}$$

Which still leaves me with $e^x $.

The method that solves it is by expanding the numerator with $e^x - e^x$ which gives us the integral:

$$\int \frac{e^x + 1 - e^x}{e^x +1}dx$$

I have seen that it works. But what compels somebody to expand the numerator with $e^x - e^x$? What benefit does a mathematician intuitively see with this? How could I be sure that it just doesn't give me back the initial integral:

$$\int\frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{e^x}$$
 ?

Comment: Now that you have a link to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770114/how-do-i-solve-displaystyle-int-frac-mathrmdxex-1, you may see from its answers that nothing _compels_ anyone to change $1$ to $e^x + 1 - e^x.$ It is merely one of several different techniques that could be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various integrals - or really, a number of problems in math (I've seen it used in real analysis for stuff involving limits by the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition) - can be solved by this technique of adding and subtracting the same thing from a quantity. For example,

$$e^t = e^t + x - x$$

This is because $x-x$ (anything minus itself) is $0$. So adding and subtracting something from itself explicitly like this is fundamentally no different from adding $0$ to something, and thus perfectly valid - if pointless at face value. But sometimes this adding and subtracting suffices in giving us a manipulation that is more handy. In this case, we see that we can split up the fraction after this manipulation:

$$\frac{1}{e^x + 1} = \frac{e^x + 1 - e^x}{e^x + 1} = \frac{e^x + 1}{e^x + 1} + \frac{-e^x}{e^x + 1} = 1 + \frac{-e^x}{e^x + 1}$$

Notice how this might be easier to integrate, namely because of a $u$-substitution of $u = e^x+1$? This manipulation lets us do that!

I'm not sure if there is some sort of underlying intuition, necessarily, beyond trying to find a method which works. Some problems are a matter of trial and error to find something which works.

*Sure, sure, in school you may often know ahead of time the method you need to use because you might be covering related material at the time and it's like "well, why would the homework be on something unrelated to the material, so obviously I'm expected to use this method that we're covering." But if a problem faces you out of the blue, say in competition mathematics or in the real world, you have less guidance and so trial and error might be necessary.*

Of course, there are other ways to solve this particular integral, as was touched on in two other answers, you need not limit yourself to one method of problem-solving.

It's just a nice little tool to have in your arsenal, one that should be kept in mind because despite its simplicity it is deceptively helpful in some cases. I don't think there's an underlying reason as to why or when it should be used other than "it works," though.

Comment: Thank you for your very thought out answer! I do also try to manipulate whenever I might see a possibility to do so. For this particular problem I could not recognize any methods of manipulating inorder to help me. I actively try to not limit myself to methods discussed in the chapter, but I could not see how somebody would think of expanding the numerator by $e^x - e^x$.

Comment: The other key point about this solution is that you have to think _two_ or even _three_ steps (depending on how you count a "step") ahead, not just one. Because once you apply the trick you don't _directly_ get $du$ - instead, you have to first do the cancellation and then apply linearity before you have a $\frac{du}{u}$ form. But often this type of thinking is not taught - either you are born with it naturally or have to sweet laddie luckie have the right people to teach you this habit.

Comment: @peter.petrov - do you think that the skill for "competition" maths gives a huge edge in actual usage of maths in more sophisticated disciplines like research or application and this if you (meaning this poster writing this specific comment) didn't develop that to participate in that kind of thing then you are at a tremendous disadvantage that means you should give up or settle?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer I don't think anyone should give up. If one has interest in math they should play with it no matter what. I don't consider myself too talented in math (meaning I have seen contestants way smarter than me) but so what... Also as I said I am not sure what fraction is the talent and what fraction is the systematic every day work. I don't know if Einstein really really said this but I like this thought: “intuition is nothing but the outcome of earlier intellectual experience”...

Comment: For absolute clarity: "This is because x−x (anything minus itself) is 0" is valid when $x$ is finite.

Answer (score 9):

Hint:
$$\frac1{e^x+1}=\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}.$$

And since the derivative of $1+e^{-x}$ is $-e^{-x}$, this suggests a useful substitution.

Comment: NO need of substitution: it is already of the form $$\;-\int\frac{f'}f \,dx=\log|f|+C\;$$

Comment: $-\log|f|\;$ , of course.

Comment: Cheers @Alejandro . So ideally when solving similar problems you want to find a common factor?

Comment: @DonAntonio The substitution suggested is $f=1+e^{-x}$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I know. Still it isn't needed as if one recognizes the integrand as $\;\frac{f'}f\;$ , then the integral is immediate.

Answer (score 7):

You can still substitute $u=e^x, \frac{du}{u} = dx$, and solve the integral. It's a perfectly valid choice for a substitution.
$$\int \frac{1}{e^x+1}dx = \int \frac{1}{(u+1)u}du  $$
You proceed by fractional decomposition of $\frac{1}{(u+1)u}$.