# Find ab if $\int \:\frac{dx}{\left(e^x+1\right)}=ax+bln\left(e^x+1\right)+C$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find ab if

$$
\int \frac{dx}{e^x+1}=ax+b\ln\left(e^x+1\right)+C
$$

Comment: Yes, I've done that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770114/how-do-i-evaluate-int-frac-mathrmdxex-1

Comment: Not really, i just started learning integrals and I am completely new :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$I=\int\frac{1}{e^x+1}dx$$

then start with the $u$-substitution $u=e^x+1\implies du=e^x dx\iff dx=\frac{du}{e^x}=\frac{du}{u-1}$ so that $$I=
\int\frac{1}{e^x+1}dx=\int\frac{1}{u}\cdot\frac{du}{u-1}=\int\frac{du}{u(u-1)}$$

Can you continue?

Comment: $-\ln \left|e^x+1\right|+x+C$ is this right?